# How to make line width for custom line in html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I want to change a line width but why all lines width in canvas is also changed?

Bellow is my code snippet

```js
let c_canvas = document.getElementById("c");
let context = c_canvas.getContext("2d");
let gradientFill = context.createLinearGradient(400, 0, 95, 305);
gradientFill.addColorStop(0, "rgba(195, 42, 28, 1.000)");
gradientFill.addColorStop(0.6, "rgba(252, 239, 55, 1.000)");
gradientFill.addColorStop(1, "rgba(12, 151, 206, 1.000)");
context.fillStyle = gradientFill;
context.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    context.beginPath();
for (let x = 0.5; x <= 501; x += 100) {
  context.moveTo(x, 0);
  context.lineTo(x, 500);

}

for (let y = 0.5; y <= 501; y += 100) {
  context.moveTo(0, y);
  context.lineTo(500, y);
}

  context.lineWidth = 1;
  context.stroke(); // Draw it
  
let frectx = 100;
let frecty = 450;
let lrectx = 250;
let lrecty = 340;
let radius = 15; // for example
let font = "bold " + radius + "px serif";
let text = "1";
let rand =[];
for(let i=0; i<5; i++)
{
rand[i] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

}

rand.forEach(function(entry,i) {
text = i+1;
frectx = entry*70;
frecty = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1)*50;

context.moveTo(frectx, frecty);
context.lineTo(lrectx, lrecty);
  context.lineWidth = 8;

context.strokeStyle = "#ddd";
context.stroke();
context.fillStyle = "white";

context.beginPath();
context.arc(frectx, frecty, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
context.fill();
context.fillStyle = "black"; // font color to write the text with

context.font = font;
context.textBaseline = "top";
context.fillText(text, frectx - radius / 4, frecty - radius / 2);

context.fillStyle = "white";

context.beginPath();
context.arc(lrectx, lrecty, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
context.stroke();
context.closePath();
context.fill();
context.fillStyle = "black"; // font color to write the text with
context.font = font;
context.textBaseline = "top";
context.fillText(text, lrectx - radius / 4, lrecty - radius / 2);
})
```

```html
<canvas id="c" width="501px" height="501px"></canvas>
```

or you can see in jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/dyaskur/t4fgLs73/

How to only change width in that lines inside the box?

My second question is how to make my line and circle transform to glow/change color when i hover on it?

Comment: You need to call `....beginPath()` when you start drawing something else. Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/muj2fezv/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `context.beginPath()` is missing between

```
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.stroke(); // Draw it
```

and

```
context.lineTo(lrectx, lrecty);
  context.lineWidth = 8;

context.strokeStyle = "#ddd";
context.stroke();
```

Without the `beginPath` call you are simply re-stroking all or the paths and subpaths already defined with the new stroke style and width.

The general answer to the second part of your question is that you don't get to do this.

Painting a canvas is equivalent to drawing an image. You can work out where the mouse is over the image, but you would then need to work out (in your program) if the mouse is over some pixels you want to change and redraw the canvas if it is.

If you want to use CSS `:hover` pseudo classes to change presentation you will need to construct the source code of an SVG element for the graphic, create the element from the source code generated, and supply appropriate CSS for the SVG element's child nodes that will be affected by mouse position.